# C# JSON Deserialize a string to a time

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I am trying to find an easy way if it exists, to take a string as part of an Json object that represents a time as such

Edit: The time string comes in without a colon.

```
{
   "time" : "1700"
}
```

and convert it to a DateTime Object during the DeSerialization.

I tried creating a "Custom Converter" using IsoDateTimeConverter, but I think I missed something, or do not fully understand.

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "HH:mm";
    }    
}


   [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
```

I understand I could alway just convert the property after the fact, but was hoping there was a way.

Answer (score 2):

What would be the expected date of that `DateTime` object? If you're willing to store time only, `TimeSpan` is probably a better structure for you.

```
class YourClass
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

Time formatted as `"17:00"` should get deserialized to `TimeSpan` out of the box for you.

Comment: It is "pulled" everyday, so ultimately the date would be the current day. It will be used to compare the current DateTime, as well as create Scheduled events.  So I could use it for the comparing.  I will figure out how to use it for Creating said events. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, This worked in my tests, however I just found the actual data, comes in without the colon (:),  so I will need to convert/format it first.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually `TimeSpan`, not `DateTime`.

This is your model:

```
public class TimeModel
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I've converted it:

```
string json = "{\"time\" : \"17:00\"}";
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeModel>(json);
Console.WriteLine(model.Time); //output: 17:00:00
```

I'm using **Newtonsoft.Json**.